# How to save or update data based on 2 condition instead of with primary id only in cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am using cakePHP 3.6, I am making some api call and on each call I am getting so many data which I am saving with `saveMany`. But here I am facing one problem, the data which is coming from the api can be existing into my database or some are new. So What I am doing is, if data with the `primary key` is already present then that row I am updating and if data with that primary key is not present then those data I am saving as a new record. Those are mostly getting cared by CakePHP default behaviour as I am using `saveMany`. Now what I want is, instead of only primary key check, I want to check with another column as well to update a row. For instance, my table have some named as `id, email, date, user_id, api_id` . Now I want to update a row if data came from api matched with `api_id` and `user_id` not only with the `api_id`.

This is what I am doing to save api response data.

```
$entityData = $this->UpdateCalendarAppointments->newEntities($aptFromApi);`

$this->UpdateCalendarAppointments->saveMany($entityData);`
```

Here `$aptFromApi` have array of data. Which is coming from `api`. Here is the sample data which is present in `$aptFromApi` variable.

```
[
'email' => 'example@gmail.com',
'date' => '2021-01-01',
'user_id' => 100,
'api_id' => 10
];
```

So What I am trying to achieve is, if `api_id is 10` and `user_id is 100` then that column should be updated otherwise it should create a new record into the database.

This is how my `UpdateCalendarAppointments` model `initialize` function looks like.

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    parent::initialize($config);
    $this->setDisplayField('api_id');
    $this->setPrimaryKey('api_id');
}
```

Those are the all I have done so far.

Comment: Cake just wants to save entities. So, give it one. Try to read the entity that matches the conditions. If it doesn't exist, create a new one. Either way, now you have something you can save.

Comment: Could you please give me some instruction here.

Comment: I thought I did... These are all very basic operations. `find()->where([...])->first()`, then either `patchEntity` or `createEntity` depending on the results of that.